# Update Bounds of JButtons, JFrame, & etc?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to update the bounds of a button when I run in Debug mode with Eclipse. I'm just needing help with this or a link to a website just so I don't have to keep restarting my program after editing some code. I want it to autoupdate when using Debug mode.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Its not web application where you can play with css on the fly. I offer you to write simple test application that launch quickly and where you can do your playground

Comment: Ok, cause I like when I can debug code and watch buttons move so I can position is correctly.

Comment: Search for Swing editors

Comment: `I can debug code and watch buttons move so I can position is correctly` - the buttons should not be moving. Instead you should be using "layout managers". It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of the components on a panel. Don't use setBounds(...). Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I meant while debugging if I change a buttons position it moves where I changed it. That's what I meant there. Sorry, I didn't get much sleep because I've been study java day & night.